# Image squashed as browser width decreases

Tags: html, css, browser, width

I'm really stuck on this browser sizing issue, where every time I make the browser width smaller, it squashes the image and then the image isn't really properly proportioned.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/LaLt4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myCounter = 0;
    $('.slides').cycle({
        fx:     'none',
        speed:   80,
        timeout: 80,
        timeoutFn: calculateTimeout
    }).cycle("pause");

    function calculateTimeout( currElement, nextElement, opts, isForward) { 
        // here we set even number slides to have a 2 second timeout; 
        // by returning false for odd number slides we let those slides 
        // inherit the default timeout value (4 sec) 
        myCounter++; 
        return myCounter % 8 ? 50 : 2000; 
    } 
}); // END doc ready

// The other function to start cycling
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume'); 


});
```

I have been struggling with this sooooo long now and cant get it to do what the website above does.

```
<body>

<div class="container">   
<div class="slideshow-block">

    <ul class="slides">

        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/person/images/person%201.jpg" class="demo-img"></li>

        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/person/images/person%202.jpg" class="demo-img"></li>

        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/person/images/person%203.jpg" class="demo-img"></li>

        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/person/images/person%204.jpg" class="demo-img"></li>

        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/person/images/person%205.jpg" class="demo-img"></li>

        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/person/images/person%206.jpg" class="demo-img"></li>

        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/person/images/person%207.jpg" class="demo-img"></li>

        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/person/images/person%208.jpg" class="demo-img"></li>

        <li><img src="http://www.example.com/person/images/person%209.jpg" class="demo-img"></li>

    </ul>

</div>

</div>

</div> 

</body>
```

CSS

```
.slides{
    position:fixed;; 
    z-index:-1; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    margin-top:-75px;   

}

.slides img{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-top:-75px;

}

#bgimage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%; 
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: The problem you're going to run into is that at some point the aspect ratio of the image isn't going to fit: http://jsfiddle.net/LaLt4/1/ I've dealt with this is [with Javascript](http://www.huckabee-inc.com/en/index.html). The page you link to, though uses `background-size: cover` as @nathvarun suggests.

Answer (score 2):

If you set both the height and width explicitly, it will not be able to maintain proportion.

What you are looking for can be achieved by using the image as a background:

```
#bgimage{
background:url('http://www.slynkon.com/alison/images/Alison%20Levi%203.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover
}
```

[**DEMO PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/eiVwnEQx4MI6EoqhX8ma?p=preview)

Some more options : http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

user `object-fit` property to fixing it. in my case, I have fixed using

```
<img 
    src="http://www.example.com/person/images/person%201.jpg" 
    style="object-fit: cover;">
```